# Creating New Tables dynamically but no Tables to be seen after creation

Tags: c#, sql-server

I started new with C# and SQL Server (Visual Studio). I am writing an app that among others create a new database files (`.mdf`) dynamically and creates three tables in the database.

I got the code to execute without any problems or throwing exceptions. The `.mdf` file and log file are created. But connecting with Visual Studio Server explorer to the file to see what is going on on the inside, I found that there are no tables to be seen.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    string[] tableSQLLines = GetTableCreateLines();

    cmd.CommandText = strSQL;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    for (int i = 0; i <= tableSQLLines.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = tableSQLLines[i];
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

The SQL statements would look like this:

```
newTableString[3] = "CREATE TABLE Photos (" +
                "PhotoID INT IDENTITY(1,1)," +
                "PhotoFileName varchar(255)," +
                "DateTaken datetime2(7)," +
                "Panoramic bit NOT NULL," +
                "PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhotoID] ASC)" +
                ");";
```

`GetTableCreateLines` returns an array of strings with the SQL create statements to create the tables. As you can see then I loop through the list and create the tables

Comment: Just a simple question: Did you right click on the database name on the Server Explorer of the Visual Studio and selected refresh after run your code?

Comment: Yes I did. I actually even created a new connection and still the same.

Comment: I have found the problem.  Thank you @flaviofrancisco for your effort.  It seems that after my initial creation of the database, it is a good idea to close the connection and reconnect to the newly created database and also attach to it with the AttachDBFilename parameter in the connection string.  And then create the new tables in the database.  Well this worked for me now.  Should there be a better solution please let me know.